# Best way to derive a type with only the own properties of another in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, interface

Given the `interface`s (these could also be `class`es):

```
interface A { a: number }
interface B { b: number }
interface C extends B { c: number }
```

How do I get (derive) a `type` from `C` that only contains its *own properties*, and not the inherited ones?

```
type Cown = ???<C>
```

---

What I've tried is:

```
type Cown = Omit<C, keyof B>
```

This seems to work, but is this the beste way?

Comment: I would say this is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript types don't keep track of how they came to be. Typescript doesn't remember how they got made. The types are only the result of their type declarations.

This means that `own` properties aren't really something that is part of the type system at all.

So given that, I think you've already found the right answer. Since a type doesn't know where it's parts came from, you simply have remove whatever parts of that type you don't want.  And this snippet does exactly that:

```
type Cown = Omit<C, keyof B>
```